# Merging data of 2 datatable columns and displaying as 1 column in datatgridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, oledb

This is my query

```
cmd2 = new OleDbCommand("Select TOP " + PageSize + " PatientID,PFirstName,PLastName,RegDate,MobileNo,PEmailID from Patient_Registration ORDER BY PatientID", con);
```

I am filling datatable with this `cmd2`

```
// con.Open();
this.adp1.SelectCommand = cmd2;
this.adp1.Fill(dt);
```

Now I want to merge `PFirstName,PLastName` column so that I can display them as a one column in datagridview ,How can i do this 
I tried something like this ,but its not working

```
dt.Columns.Add("FullName", typeof(string), "PFirstName + ' ' + PLastName");
```

Comment: try to do that in your query `OledDbCommand`

Comment: @SaghirA.Khatri I don't know how to do that in query ,Can you Plaese show code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do something like this

```
cmd2 = new OleDbCommand("Select TOP " + PageSize + " PatientID,PFirstName&' '&PLastName as 'Full Name',RegDate,MobileNo,PEmailID from Patient_Registration ORDER BY PatientID", con);
```

here is sql fiddle link for reference http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/abc6b/1

Comment: It's not SQL it is MS ACCESS please refer http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/concat.php

Comment: @SaghirA.Khatri what if I want column name as `Full Name`

Comment: did you check the edited code. i have added space in `FullName` to make it `Full Name`

Answer (score 1):

You may add a **Full Name** column to the DataGridView and set it manually in the `DataBindingComplete` event.

Like this:

```
DataTable dt;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // sample data
    dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("FirstName", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("LastName", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));

    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Andrew", "Jones", 5 });
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Steve", "Jobs", 15 });
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Surendar", "Sani", 10 });

    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

    // Make DataGridView columns
    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dgvtxtFullName = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    dgvtxtFullName.HeaderText = "Full Name";

    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dgvAge = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    dgvAge.HeaderText = "Age";
    dgvAge.DataPropertyName = "Age";

    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvtxtFullName);
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvAge);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}

private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    // Loop through each DataGridViewRow to set the full name column
    foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (!item.IsNewRow)
        {
            string FullName = string.Format("{0} {1}",
                dt.Rows[item.Index]["FirstName"], dt.Rows[item.Index]["LastName"]);
            item.Cells[0].Value = FullName;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to concatenate string is **&** You can possibly do that in your query itself.

Change your Query to

```
cmd2 = new OleDbCommand("Select TOP " + PageSize + " PatientID,[PFirstName]&" "&[ PLastName] as [Full Name],RegDate,MobileNo,PEmailID from Patient_Registration ORDER BY PatientID", con);
```

you can refer [this](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/concat.php)

Comment: @SaghirA.Khatri It does please take a look at my updated answer

Comment: btw your code is still error prone as you have used double quotes where you are concatenating instead of single quote...

Comment: @Durga Glad it worked Please feel free to mark it as your acccepted answer

Comment: I have already accepted `Saghir A. Khatri's` answer ,I have upvoted your answer as both code works fine